# How to add variable key/value pair to list object?

Tags: list, r

I have two variables, `key` and `value`, and I want to add them as a key/value pair to a list:

```
key = "width"
value = 32

mylist = list()
mylist$key = value
```

The result is this:

```
mylist
# $key
# [1] 32
```

But I would like this instead:

```
mylist
# $width
# [1] 32
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

R lists can be thought of as hashes- vectors of objects that can be accessed by name. Using this approach you can add a new entry to the list like so:

```
key <- "width"
value <- 32

mylist <- list()
mylist[[ key ]] <- value
```

Here we use the string stored in the variable key to access a position in the list much like using the value stored in a loop variable i to access a vector through:

```
vector[ i ]
```

The result is:

```
myList
$width
[1] 32
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't really understand this indexing operator yet. Although it is explained here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing, the usage you showed is not described. Is there any online doc where this is described properly?

Comment: If the values are basic types (e.g. single numeric, character, etc.) you can use a regular array such as: x <- c(1, 4, 2, 5).  Then assign names to each index value like: names(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd').  You can then refer to them as x['a'], x['b'], etc.

Answer (score 28):

The `setNames()` built-in function makes it easy to create a hash from given key and value lists.  *(Thanks to Nick K for the better suggestion.)*

Usage: `hh <- setNames(as.list(values), keys)`

Example:

```
players <- c("bob", "tom", "tim", "tony", "tiny", "hubert", "herbert")
rankings <- c(0.2027, 0.2187, 0.0378, 0.3334, 0.0161, 0.0555, 0.1357)
league <- setNames(as.list(rankings), players)
```

Then accessing the values through the keys is easy:

> ```
> league$bob
>  [1] 0.2027
> league$hubert
>  [1] 0.0555
> ```

Answer (score 16):

List elements in R can be named.  So in your case just do

```
 > mylist = list()
 > mylist$width = value
```

When R encounters this code

```
> l$somename=something
```

where l is a list. It appends to a list an element something, and names it with name somename. It is then can be accessed by using

```
> l[["somename"]]
```

or

```
> l$somename
```

The name can be changed with command names:

```
> names(l)[names(l)=="somename"] <- "othername"
```

Or if you now the position of the element in the list by:

```
> names(l)[1] <- "someothername"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use R's list data structure to store data in the form of key-value pair.

Syntax:

`ObjectName<-list("key"= value)`

Example:

`mylist<-list("width"=32)`

also, refer example: ["https://github.com/WinVector/zmPDSwR/blob/master/Statlog/GCDSteps.R"](https://github.com/WinVector/zmPDSwR/blob/master/Statlog/GCDSteps.R)