# push to list in R

Tags: list, r

OK, this really basic. How do I add an element to a (named) list in R?

**EDIT**
when the key name is a varibale

```
for (name in names(list$filenames)) {
  filename <- list$filenames[[name]]
  x <- read.table(filename)
  ret$name <- x # I want name to be interpreted here, not use "name"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: How to add variable key/value pair to list object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105659/r-how-to-add-variable-key-value-pair-to-list-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `ret<-lapply(list$filenames,read.table)` will be better?

Comment: maybe in this case it will, but I would happy to know hot to generally do it.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

```
ret$name <- x # I want name to be interpreted here, not use "name"
```

That's the same thing as this:

```
ret[["name"]]
```

Do this instead:

```
ret[name]
```

Or if you want a simple vector back rather than something as the same type as ret, do this:

```
ret[[name]]
```