# mutable naming list elements at initialization without eval(parse(paste()))

Tags: r, list, naming

My question is similar to [How to add variable key/value pair to list object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105659/how-to-add-variable-key-value-pair-to-list-object). I want to give a list element a mutable name according to the value of a variable. But I do not want to *rename* the list, but name it correctly *right at initialization* (I want a one liner) without using "[The evil trio (eval,
parse, paste)](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/272790.html)".

The "problem" of how `list` works is that

```
key <- "width" 
my_list <- list(key = 32)
```

names the element (understandably) `"key"` and not `"width"`, even if `key <- "width"` and one is eager to have the same result as `my_list <- list(width = 32)`.

The "evil trio solution" would be `my_list <- eval(parse(text = paste("list(", key, "=32)")))`, but I am looking for a more elegant solution like `list(eval(key) = 32)` (which doesn't work).

Comment: I deleted my answer since it's already [given in the Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31298923/3521006) linked in the question. IMO, it's the best option

Comment: @docendodiscimus In general I agree with you, but unfortunately this nice answer has (with my upvote) only 3 votes and is not straight forward to recognize as an suitable answer (as Assad Ebrahim talks about a "hash" and his code doesn't use the code from the OP). So feel free to post your answer again (I'll delete my own answer then of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus) gave the answer `setNames(list(32), key)` but "deleted [his] answer since it's already [given in the Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105659/how-to-add-variable-key-value-pair-to-list-object/31298923#31298923) linked in the question."

Unfortunately this nice answer there has (with my upvote) only 3 votes and is not straight forward to recognize as an suitable answer (as Assad Ebrahim talks about a "hash" and his code doesn't use the code from the OP).